# ko.getObservable is not a function in admin section

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, static-content

After updating may Magento2 instance to [commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0be91a56d050791ac0b67a47185d79df31e79329) I am seeing the error `ko.getObservable is not a function` in the file `events.js`.

I have performed and composer install, bin/magento update and bin/magento static content deploy, but still see this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` does not remove the old versions by default. So once I deleted the `pub/static` folder and re-ran the script then the error disappeared.

Comment: I have done the same but issue still persist